# What is p(data) in image generation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, density-function, image-processing

In the context of image generation architectures such as VAEs or GANs (say we are using mnist digits) what do we mean by probability distribution of the data?

Just to clarify this question and make it more specific - to motivate an answer. I am looking at this paper: [Score-Based Generative Modeling through Stochastic Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13456)

The best clue is in the appendix p.32 - they mention $p_0(X(0)|y)=p(x|y)$ where $X(0)$ is the data (images) and $y$ is some label.

**How do you model p(x|y) - what distribution?**

*** **Update** ***

Instead of deleting the question - I am going to provide some insight on score based diffusion methods.

First of all $p(data)$, in the context of image generation, refers to the initial distribution of all images; hence, it is not known. The datasets that we have are samples from that distribution but we cannot know the distribution itself.

Two things we have to know about the method:

1. What is a diffusion process (X)
2. What is a conditioned diffusion or reversed diffusion (X*)

All I am going to say here is that the conditioned diffusion can take us back from to the distribution of the diffusion initial condition X(t=0). This is equivalent to the distribution of $p(data)$; Therefore, we can sample new images from it.

Now at the core of the conditioned diffusion is a thing called the score function. We let an algorithm with enough capacity approximate this function, i.e.: a neural network. If you have a loss function then one can train a neural network to learn whatever it is.

Here is a quick illustration of the gist of the diffusion score methods:

[image]

Comment: There are a couple things this could mean (empirical distribution, marginal likelihood); can you show an example of the context where you saw the expression being used?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I was just hinted that when we refer to probability distribution over a dataset - we mean how likely is an image to be a part of the dataset - but it isn't something we can calculate with a formula i.e.: count pixels

Comment: Well, the simplest probability distribution over your dataset of $N$ images is that each of those images gets probability $1/N$ and everything else gets probability $0$.

Comment: This gives most of the theoretical explanation: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54346/data-generating-probability-distribution-probability-distribution-of-a-dataset

Comment: So you've found your answer—great.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Definitely part of the answer - but I was hoping we could assume $p_{true}(data|label) = p(dataset|label)$ and model that somehow with a bunch of gaussians. All I can do is calculate the probability $p(image|label)$ - I can't determine what the distribution is

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I actually understand now =) Academic papers are so confusing

Comment: Rather than editing the question with what you've learned, I think you could help future users by posting it as an answer.